# Why does SortedSet<T> ignore CompareTo() values of 0 by default?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

When I try to AddRange to a SortedSet, it doesn't add values when their compareto result is zero. This doesn't make any sense to me, as it's not a SortedSet of the values that compareTo is comparing, it's a SortedSet of T. I am trying to understand why Microsoft would implement it like this.

1. Is there any logical explanation to this that will help me remember in the future?
2. Is the correct way to implement IComparable on my type by not returning 0 from CompareTo? What happens if I need CompareTo to determine equality explicitly when I use its IComparable.CompareTo() method elsewhere in my code?

Comment: I've answered your first question - I don't understand what you mean by the second question at all; it's *very, very* unclear.

Comment: I updated it. Hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: Um, maybe. I'll edit my answer, and you can see what you want to do...

Answer (score 2):

It would make a SortedSet non-deterministic

[SortedSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Represents a collection of objects that is maintained in sorted order.

If ties were allowed there would be an arbitrary order.  It would be like duplicate keys in a dictionary.

If you want a set of T with some that return 0 from compare to then SortSet is not the proper collection.

I get the feeling this is a bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of the comparison is to say whether one item is greater than, less than or equal to another. A set doesn't allow equal values - and in a sorted set, equality is defined by the comparison. It's as simple as that.

For your second question, it sounds like you want to have two different comparisons - one which returns 0 in certain cases where the other one wouldn't. You can do that by implementing `IComparer<T>` in a separate class, as the separate comparison. Just bear in mind that you'll still want to return 0 for `Compare(x, x)` for example, otherwise you'd never be able to find anything in the set other than by iterating over it...

Comment: There are two different comparisons--the one implemented by `Object.Equals` and `IEqualityComparer<T>.Equals`, and the one implemented by `IComparable<T>.CompareTo` and `IComparer<T>.Compare`, and there are times when it may make sense for them to collectively report that two items are unordered with respect to each other but are nonetheless not equal.  Such behavior might have made sense e.g. with `Decimal` values 12.3m and 12.30m; neither is larger than the other, but a strong argument could be made that their `Equals` method should report them as different (e.g. if one wants to use a...

Comment: `Dictionary<Decimal,String>` to cache string representations, the value 12.3m should map to string "12.3" and 12.30m to string "12.30").  I believe Java's `BigDecimal` type has different behavior for `equals` and `compareTo` for essentially that reason.